httpStatus.getReasonPhrase() method not available in httpStatusCode
I have an implementation in the code like
public class Custom extends OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint{
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<?> enhanceResponse(ResponseEntity<?> response, Exception exception){
        ResponseEntity ret = super.enhanceResponse(response, exception);
        return new ResponseEntity(ErrorResponse500.builder().message(Exception.getMessage()).code(ret.getStatusCode().getReasonPhrase()).build(), ret.getHeaders(), ret.getStatusCode());
}

Here, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus has changed to org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode which does not contain getReasonPhrase()
How can I get reason phrase from HttpStatusCode?

"How can I get reason phrase from HttpStatusCode?" You can't. But the real question should be: Why do you need that?
